# In Excel I want to add a list of hours and minutes entries (flight time)

Tags: excel, time

I have a monthly flight log over a 20-plus-year time span.  The log format is hh:mm where total hours and minutes for a given period of time are entered.  The time period varies (it could be a day, or a few months with one entry).  I want to add hours and minutes using Excel to achieve periodic totals and accumulative totals brought forward.  No dates or time of day entries are used.  I can do all types of math using dates and time of day but can't figure out how to add hours and minutes with the result of total hours:minutes.  ie, 27:59 (hh:mm) + 3:10 should equal 31:09.  Again, to be clear, I'm not entering a time-of-day reference or a date but hours and minutes.

At the end of the whole exercise, I will have a lifetime of total hours flown which is how pilots record and accumulate their time.  X number of hours in one aircraft and Y number in another aircraft equals a total number of flying hours.

Comment: If the times are "real times" (test with `ISNUMBER`), then just add them, but you must format the results as `[hh]:mm` in order to display hours > 24.

Comment: How is this a programming question? Maybe it is, but it's not clear from the description. Questions about how to use Excel are off-topic.

Comment: @gert Arnold I see a lot of other Excel questions in stackoverflow, just related to formulas or other, first time someone says it is off topic. How can one know it is off topic? There should be some rules somewhere.

Comment: @Prema It's probably quite arbitrary (as anything that grows from consensus), but I think anything related to what can be done through Excel's front-end is in the category of questions about an application. Questions related to VBA in Excel are programming questions. Fact is that the description isn't really clear. A sample would help.

Comment: Also, see the tag description. Excel formulas are a [grey area](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261875/are-excel-formulas-on-topic).